# OpenSSH client cannot connect to host using its hostname

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

I have a SSH server on my (enterprise) Windows network, with hostname (defined in `/etc/hostname`) `Applications`. On the network, it appears as `APPLICATIONS`. (I don't know why the whole name is uppercased….)

When I use my Windows 10 session, I can connect to the server using PuTTY (with hostname `APPLICATIONS`). However, when I use my Linux Mint session & OpenSSH client, I’m unable to connect to it using its hostname, whatever case I use (`Applications`, `APPLICATIONS`, `applications`) but I’m still able to connect to it via its local IP.

When I try to connect, I get the following error message:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname applications: Temporary failure in name resolution.

Note that hostname is written lower-case, whatever the case I use in my `ssh` command, so I wonder if it's the cause of the client not being able to connect to the server.

Do you know where does this problem comes from? And, more important, how can I solve it?

Comment: Check the IP settings of the machine with the issue and check the DNS in particular. A potential starting point at least.

Comment: Does anything else resolve on that linux installation? Eg. ping? Or is this limited only to ssh?

Comment: @Elias `ping (APPLICATIONS|Applications|applications)` gives an `unknown host` error. However, I can access SAMBA share (hostname shown in file viewer is `APPLICATIONS`, but in the "navigation bar" it's shown lowercase.

Comment: Samba shares are often shown without proper dns but if ping doesn't resolve then it just won't happen. Did you have an entry in the hosts file on the mint machine or should this be resolved via a dns server?

Answer (score 0):

Your Linux Mint machine should have an entry in /etc/hosts too, for instance:

```
192.168.0.3   applications
```

Your `ssh` client needs to connect to a known hostname, yet the casing in hostname resolution does not matter at all; domain names are case insensitive.

At the moment it cannot resolve it using DNS, so it falls back to /etc/hosts.

It could be that you are mot root on linux, in that case you can edit the file `$HOME/.ssh/config` like:

```
Host applications
    Host 192.168.0.3
```